# How do I get Sketch shapes to scale in template?

Tags: sketch-app

I am using a template to make iOS app icons, see file at link below. Some of the shapes on the Symbols page scale correctly when applied to the Templates page (ears, head). However, the two curved lines I am using for the mouth do not.

How can I fix this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8oqb0xojd90ro02/application-icons.sketch?dl=0

[image]

Comment: I don't use Inskape, but there must be an option as in Illustrator **Scale Strokes & Effects** when transforming.

Comment: @Danielillo - the question is for Sketch, not Inkscape. Nevertheless, your comment is still applicable - nearly all vector image editors have a way of enabling scaling of strokes, which seems to be the OP's problem.

Comment: Oh, ______ sorry 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Sketch always scales the border width when resizing symbol instances.

The only workarounds I know about is to convert the borders to paths using `Layer > Convert to outlines` or by detaching the symbol instance and use `Layer > Transform > Scale...` to resize the object.

Comment: Layer > Convert to outlines worked well. Thanks!